# Understanding $args in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I don't understand the output of my powershell function.

```
function test($args) { $y = $args+2 ; "$y"}
```

INPUT:

> test 1 2 3 0

OUTPUT:

> 2 3 0 2

my expected OUTPUT:

> 3 4 5 2

It seems that I didn't understand how `$args` is working. I would be very happy with any explanations.

Additional question:
How can I get my expected Output 3 4 5 2 without using a predefined variable?

Comment: PowerShell's operators don't work that way. You can't use `<array> + x` as a shorthand for mapping a function over a collection, you'd have to use something like `$args.foreach{$_ + 2}` (there are other syntaxes, but that's the shortest one). If you don't like `$args`, explicitly pass an array: `test @(1, 2, 3, 0)` and then you can name your parameter whatever you like.

Comment: Don't declare `$args` in your param block, it's an automatic variable.

Comment: [$Args](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#args)

Answer (score 0):

Please rename the variable name $args to any other name that is no automatic variable.
You can get an overview using help.

```
    help about_automatic_variable
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it this way.  $y and $args are arrays, but "$y" becomes stringified.

```
function test { $y = $args | foreach-object { $_ + 2 }; "$y"  }

test 1 2 3 0
3 4 5 2
```